# how to delete the events after drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id='wrap'>
    <div id='external-events'>
        <div id='external-events-listing'>
            <h4>Channel List</h4>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    // Manage status of dragging event and calendar
    var calEventStatus = [];


    /* Required functions */

        var isEventOverDiv = function(x, y) {

            var external_events = $( '#external-events' );
            var offset = external_events.offset();
            offset.right = external_events.width() + offset.left;
            offset.bottom = external_events.height() + offset.top;

            // Compare
            if (x >= offset.left
                && y >= offset.top
                && x <= offset.right
                && y <= offset .bottom) { return true; }
            return false;

        }


        function makeEventsDraggable () { 

          $('.fc-draggable').each(function() {

          // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
              $(this).data('event', {
                  title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                  stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
              });

              // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
              $(this).draggable({
                  zIndex: 999,
                  revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                  revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
              });

              console.log('makeEventsDraggable');

              // Dirty fix to remove highlighted blue background
              $("td").removeClass("fc-highlight");

      });

      }



        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

            // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
            $(this).data('event', {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
            });

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });

        });


        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
            dragRevertDuration: 0,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui) { console.log('calendar drop'); console.log(date); console.log(jsEvent); console.log(ui); console.log(this);
                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }

                // if event dropped from another calendar, remove from that calendar
                if (typeof calEventStatus['calendar'] != 'undefined') {
                  $(calEventStatus['calendar']).fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEventStatus['event_id']);
                  //$(calEventStatus['calendar']).fullCalendar('unselect');
        }

                makeEventsDraggable();
            },
            eventReceive: function( event ) {  console.log('calendar eventReceive');
              makeEventsDraggable();
            },
            eventDrop: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {  console.log('calendar eventDrop');
              makeEventsDraggable();
            },
            eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
              console.log(event); console.log(jsEvent); console.log(ui); console.log(view);

              // Add dragging event in global var 
              calEventStatus['calendar'] = '#calendar';
              calEventStatus['event_id'] = event._id;
              console.log('calendar eventDragStart');
            },
            eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { console.log('calendar eventDragStop');

                if(isEventOverDiv(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY)) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                    var el = $( "<div class='fc-event'>" ).appendTo( '#external-events-listing' ).text( event.title );
                    el.draggable({
                      zIndex: 999,
                      revert: true, 
                      revertDuration: 0 
                    });
                    el.data('event', { title: event.title, id :event.id, stick: true });
                }

                calEventStatus = []; // Empty
                makeEventsDraggable();
            },
            eventResize: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
                makeEventsDraggable();
            },
            viewRender: function() { console.log('calendar viewRender');
                makeEventsDraggable();
            },
        });

    });
```

i am drag and dropping events from Channel list into calender, after that under which "id" or "class" it is stored(that dropped event). and how can i delete/remove an event after dropping(some what like onclick of event, it should delete.
[Complete code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AsifAadeez/dgf9g8z0/2/)
 thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this code**

Add this code in your drop function

```
drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui) {
    $(ui.helper).remove();
    $(ui.draggable).remove();
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgf9g8z0/3/)

**updated**

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scheduler</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <style type="text/css">
    button.remove {
    font-size: .85em;
    border: 1px solid #3a87ad;
    background-color: #3a87ad;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 3px 0;
}
calender-body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}
.fc-content span.close {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#wrap {
  width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#external-events {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: left;
}

#external-events h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

#external-events .fc-event {
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#external-events p {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #666;
}

#external-events p input {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#calendar {
  float: left;
  width: 1150px;
}
.mb-20{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id='wrap'>
    <div id='external-events'>
        <div id='external-events-listing'>
            <h4>Channel List</h4>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
            <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
   <ul id="daysEvent"></ul>
            <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<!-- <script src="js/index.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

        var calEventStatus = [];


            var isEventOverDiv = function(x, y) {

                var external_events = $( '#external-events' );
                var offset = external_events.offset();
                offset.right = external_events.width() + offset.left;
                offset.bottom = external_events.height() + offset.top;

                // Compare
                if (x >= offset.left
                    && y >= offset.top
                    && x <= offset.right
                    && y <= offset .bottom) { return true; }
                return false;

            }


            function makeEventsDraggable () { 
             
              $('.fc-draggable').each(function() {

                  $(this).data('event', {
                      title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                      stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                  });

                  $(this).draggable({
                      zIndex: 999,
                      revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                      revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                  });

                  $("td").removeClass("fc-highlight");

          });

          }



            /* initialize the external events
            -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

            $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

                $(this).data('event', {
                    title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                    stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                });

                $(this).draggable({
                    zIndex: 999,
                    revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                    revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                });

            });


            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                droppable: true, 
                dragRevertDuration: 0,
                eventLimit: true, 
                drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui) {
    //$(ui.draggable).remove(); //remove from list
                    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                    if (typeof calEventStatus['calendar'] != 'undefined') {
                      $(calEventStatus['calendar']).fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEventStatus['event_id']);
    }
                    makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                eventReceive: function( event,element ) { 
     event.id = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
     //var button = '<button class="remove" data-id="' + event._id +'">Remove (' + event.start.format() + ' event)</button>';
     //$('#daysEvent').append('<li>' + button + '</li>');
     makeEventsDraggable();
                },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
     element.find(".fc-content").append("<span class='close' data-id='" + event._id +"'>x</span>");
    },
                eventDrop: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
                  makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
                  calEventStatus['calendar'] = '#calendar';
                  calEventStatus['event_id'] = event._id;
                },
                eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
                    if(isEventOverDiv(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY)) {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                        var el = $( "<div class='fc-event'>" ).appendTo( '#external-events-listing' ).text( event.title );
                        el.draggable({
                          zIndex: 999,
                          revert: true, 
                          revertDuration: 0 
                        });
                        el.data('event', { title: event.title, id :event.id, stick: true });
                    }

                    calEventStatus = []; // Empty
                    makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                eventResize: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
                    makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                viewRender: function() { 
                    makeEventsDraggable();
                },
            });
   $(document).on('click', '.close', function(){
    debugger;
    var id = $(this).data('id'); 
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', id); 
    $(this).parent().remove();
   });
      
        });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry my question was wrong may be, i want a delete option in calender to dropped "event". (i want that dragged item to be populated their even after drag and dropping)

Comment: Actually you can drop back the dropped from calender to channel list.You want another delete option again?

Comment: yeah because i will be having multiple columns where i need to drop "events"

Comment: please see this https://jsfiddle.net/166uz7L1/2/  I have added a button,and onclick dropped events get removed.

Comment: not complete calender only individual events i want to remove. that also useful thanks for that

Comment: the issue here will be is, i will not be able to know which item i will delete, so i am expecting some what like this, in this fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/5ekhtyrg/3/

Comment: Glad to help you:)

Comment: why is that month is shown by default, can i make day as default  ??  my question might look silly because i'm pure backend developer but due to some issues both are been done by me.

Comment: Yes.see this https://jsfiddle.net/166uz7L1/6/  `$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', '1992-03-06' );`

Comment: sorry but what i meant was , as you can see, there are three tabs on right side top named as "month","week",and "day" by default i want day tab to be active not month tab.

Comment: kk.just add this code `defaultView: 'agendaDay',` see this https://jsfiddle.net/166uz7L1/7/

Comment: one last thing is remaining mate ........ wen ever i complete my drag and drop ... at the end, i want data which is dropped in calender with its event name and event start & end time

Comment: its ok Amal, thank you .. i just want to know which line is causing me to resize the event in the calender div

Answer (score 0):

**Working Code Snippet :**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            // Manage status of dragging event and calendar
            var calEventStatus = [];


            /* Required functions */

            var isEventOverDiv = function (x, y) {

                var external_events = $('#external-events');
                var offset = external_events.offset();
                offset.right = external_events.width() + offset.left;
                offset.bottom = external_events.height() + offset.top;

                // Compare
                if (x >= offset.left
                    && y >= offset.top
                    && x <= offset.right
                    && y <= offset.bottom) { return true; }
                return false;

            }


            function makeEventsDraggable() {

                $('.fc-draggable').each(function () {

                    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                    $(this).data('event', {
                        title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                    });

                    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                    $(this).draggable({
                        zIndex: 999,
                        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                    });

                    // Dirty fix to remove highlighted blue background
                    $("td").removeClass("fc-highlight");

                });

            }



            /* initialize the external events
            -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

            $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () {

                // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                $(this).data('event', {
                    title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                    stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                });

                // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                $(this).draggable({
                    zIndex: 999,
                    revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                    revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                });

            });


            /* initialize the calendar
            -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
                dragRevertDuration: 0,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                drop: function (date, jsEvent, ui) {

                    $(ui.helper).remove();
                    $(ui.draggable).remove();

                    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                        $(this).remove();
                    }

                    // if event dropped from another calendar, remove from that calendar
                    if (typeof calEventStatus['calendar'] != 'undefined') {
                        $(calEventStatus['calendar']).fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEventStatus['event_id']);
                        //$(calEventStatus['calendar']).fullCalendar('unselect');
                    }

                    makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                eventReceive: function (event) {
                    
                    makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                    
                    makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                eventDragStart: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                    
                    // Add dragging event in global var
                    calEventStatus['calendar'] = '#calendar';
                    calEventStatus['event_id'] = event._id;
                    
                },
                eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                    
                    if (isEventOverDiv(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY)) {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                        var el = $("<div class='fc-event'>").appendTo('#external-events-listing').text(event.title);
                        el.draggable({
                            zIndex: 999,
                            revert: true,
                            revertDuration: 0
                        });
                        el.data('event', { title: event.title, id: event.id, stick: true });
                    }

                    calEventStatus = []; // Empty
                    makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                eventResize: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                    makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                viewRender: function () {
                    makeEventsDraggable();
                },
            });

        });
```

```css
        calender-body {
            margin-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

        #wrap {
            width: 1500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #external-events {
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background: #eee;
            text-align: left;
        }

            #external-events h4 {
                font-size: 16px;
                margin-top: 0;
                padding-top: 1em;
            }

            #external-events .fc-event {
                margin: 10px 0;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            #external-events p {
                margin: 1.5em 0;
                font-size: 11px;
                color: #666;
            }

                #external-events p input {
                    margin: 0;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                }

        #calendar {
            float: left;
            width: 1150px;
        }

        .mb-20 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    
    <div id='wrap'>
        <div id='external-events'>
            <div id='external-events-listing'>
                <h4>Channel List</h4>
                <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
                <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
                <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
                <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
                <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id='calendar'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: sorry my question was wrong may be, i want a delete option in calender to dropped "event". (i want that dragged item to be populated their even after drag and dropping)